# Easier way to find if string is a number in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm quite new to programming. I was trying to figure out how to check if a user input (which get stores as a string) is an integer and does not contain letters. I checked some stuff on the forum and in the end came up with this:

```
while 1:

#Set variables
    age=input("Enter age: ")
    correctvalue=1

#Check if user input COULD be changed to an integer. If not, changed variable to 0
    try:
        variable = int(age)
    except ValueError:
        correctvalue=0
        print("thats no age!")

#If value left at 1, prints age and breaks out of loop.
#If changed, gives instructions to user and repeats loop.
    if correctvalue == 1:
        age=int(age)
        print ("Your age is: " + str(age))
        break
    else:
        print ("Please enter only numbers and without decimal point")
```

Now, this works as shown and does what I want (ask the persons age untill they enter an integer), however is rather long for such a simple thing. I've tried to find one but I get too much data that I don't understand yet.

Is there a simple shorter way or even a simple function for this to be done?

Comment: It doesn't get much shorter actually.

Comment: Python has `True` and `False` - don't use `0` and `1` as flags. Also, whichever you use, it's just `if correctvalue:`.

Comment: I'm pretty new to the site but doesn't this belong in code review?  OP posts working code and is asking for refinement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for nonnegative integers (i.e., without a sign marker):

```
variable = ''
while True:
    variable = input("Age: ")
    if variable.isdigit():
        break
    else:
        print("That's not an age!")
variable = int(variable)
```

The idea is that you loop continuously until the user inputs a string that contains only digits (that's what [`isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) does).

Comment: You do not need `variable = ''` at the top of the while loop. I also think `try: int(x) except ValueError:` form is better in this case

Answer (score 2):

You can make this a little shorter by removing the unnecessary `correctvalue` variable and `break`ing or `continue`-ing as necessary.

```
while True:
    age=input("Enter age: ")    
    try:
        age = int(age)
    except ValueError:
        print("thats no age!")
        print ("Please enter only numbers and without decimal point")
    else:
        break

print ("Your age is: " + str(age))
```

Comment: I guess yours _is_ shorter than mine by one line :) If the `except` contains a `continue`, why use `else`?

Comment: Good question :) I think at one point I still had some code following the try statement, but forgot to remove the `continue` when I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use isdigit()

```
"34".isdigit()
>>> "34".isdigit()
True
>>> "3.4".isdigit()
False
>>>
```

So something like this:

```
while True:

    #Set variables
    age=input("Enter age: ")

    #Check 
    if not age.isdigit():
        print("thats no age!")
        continue

    print("Your age is: %s" % age)
    age = int(age)  
    break
```

Comment: Although it would do the trick for this specific age scenario, it doesn't handle negative numbers. Currently the question title ask for an integer check.

Comment: And this is not better according to most philosophies/conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be made a bit shorter like this. I was going to suggest changing your `correctvalue` variable from an integer `1` or `0` to a boolean `True` or `False` but it is redundant anyway. `continue` can be used to repeat the loop as necessary.

```
while True:

    age = input("Enter age: ")

    try:
        age = int(age)
    except ValueError:
        print("That's no age!")
        print("Please enter only numbers and without decimal point")
        continue

    print ("Your age is: " + str(age))
    break
```